# Best practice to recursively update a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, amazon-s3, hashmap

I am creating a nested dictionary in python containing entries for files stored in an Amazon S3 bucket. So if in my bucket I have a couple of files like this:

mys3bucket/subdir/world.txt

mys3bucket/subdir/hello.txt

mys3bucket/foobar.txt

I want to make a dictionary in python in this format:

```
dict = { 'subdir' : { 'world.txt' : 'file', 'hello.txt' : 'file' }, 'foobar.txt'  :'file' }
```

The values ('file') have no meaning in this context, but they could be replaced with the size of the file or something else (for this question it doesn't matter). The point is that the dictionary has to be nested because of the subdirectories, and obviously the level of nesting varies depending on how deep a particular tree is. I have written a working implementation which already does this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import httplib
from re import compile as recomp

pattern = recomp("<Key>(.*?)<\/Key>")

def main(bucketname='elasticmapreduce'):
    url = bucketname + '.s3.amazonaws.com'
    HTTPconnection = httplib.HTTPConnection(url)
    HTTPconnection.request("GET", "/")
    response = HTTPconnection.getresponse()
    content = response.read()
    fileslist = pattern.findall(content)

    filesdict = {}

  def intoDict(path,mydict):
      if len(path) == 1:
          mydict[path[0]] = 'file'
         return mydict
      else:
          name = path.pop(0)
      if name in mydict:
          mydict[name] = intoDict(path,mydict[name])
      else:
          mydict[name] = intoDict(path,{})
      return mydict

  for line in fileslist:
      splitline = line.split('/')
      if splitline[-1] != '':
          filesdict = intoDict(splitline,filesdict)

      return filesdict
```

The default bucket name is just set to a public bucket which I found to be able to test the code on.

The reason for the regex is because S3 returns an XML formatted text back when you query the bucket, so the regex just pulls out the filepaths from that.

I am curious about the efficiency of my implementation. As you can see in the for loop I am passing the whole dictionary each time to the `intoDict()` function, and re-writing it when it comes back. The `intoDict()` function is recursive/self-referencing, which is how the nesting comes about. It's a bit hard to explain what's going on, but I think you can see. It took me a while to come to this solution, because at first I was trying to use `dictionary.update()` to update the dictionary inside the `for` loop, but it wasn't working correctly.

I was wondering if anyone who is experienced in nested dictionaries and/or recursive functions can comment on whether this is correct way to achieve what I am trying, or whether it can be done better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's couple things that could be improved. Instead of using recursion you could use iteration to find the correct path to insert. You should also consider removing the mutation of the list here: `name = path.pop(0)`. You also don't need to assign the values `filesdict` on every level if they already exist just as you identified.

Here's example using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) on how to put above in practice:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# Create dict that automatically assigns empty dict to a key that doesn't exist
dd = lambda: defaultdict(dd)
filesdict = dd()

for line in fileslist:
    path = line.split('/')
    if path[-1] != '':
        d = filesdict

        # Iterate to location where file is to be added without mutating path
        for i in range(len(path) - 1):
            # If d[path[i]] doesn't exist empty dict is automatically created here
            d = d[path[i]]
        d[path[-1]] = 'file'
```

You could also consider using [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) instead `re.findall` since you process the files one by one.

Comment: Thanks @niemmi, this is really cool! 

You introduced a couple of new concepts to me here. I have changed the code to work without `defaultdict` so I have added:
`if path[i] not in d: d[path[i]] = {}`
Something I don't understand:  when we make the assignment `d = filesdict` I am guessing Python creates some kind of dynamic association between the two dictionaries? Apologies if that's a silly question.

Comment: @KirillVourlakidis Not a silly question at all. I'm not sure what you mean by dynamic association but it's just two references to same object. Now after the line `d = d[path[i]]` is executed `d` refers to child `dict` instead. When the next path is processed we need to start from root again so we need to keep reference there (`filesdict`).

Comment: That makes sense about referencing the same object! In my head I kind of imagined Python creating a copy of the whole dictionary and linking them together whereby if one is changed, it automatically changes the other, thus my 'dynamic association' comment.
As you can see I am still kind of getting my head around the whole object-oriented thing.